# How to solve Gradle Failed to resolve error for android work manager?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-architecture-components

I'm getting this error when I try to add Work Manager library to the project gradle file:

```
Failed to resolve:  android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-aplha02
```

I'm also using fabric, it's dependencies are included in the project level build.gradle. I don't think the maven repositry lines are messing up the project.

> And I wanted to also ask if it's safe to use an alpha level library in
>   production level app?

build.gradle(Module: app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'androooid'
            storePassword 'androooid'
        }
        release {
            keyAlias 'pixieee'
            keyPassword 'Hello1234'

        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pixie.pixieentertainmentsystem"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.031"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.6.1'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.danikula:videocache:2.7.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'

    implementation 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.3.2'
    //apt 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.3.2'
    implementation 'com.danikula:videocache:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-aplha02'


    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: please provide your gradle code

Comment: I just restarted the Android Studio and cleaned the project, now it's working fine.

Comment: oh..happy coding